# concurrent write in mongodb bulk update

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, bulkupdate

Does mongodb locks the db while executing bulk update?
I am using mongo bulk operation.

`var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).updateOne( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } });
bulk.find( { status: "A" } ).updateOne( { $set: { status: "B", points: "0" } });
bulk.execute();`

Assume this operation has 100 find and update, and there is another process running which is also trying to update same collection in db.

Does it have lock to prevent concurrent update?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using MongoDB version >= 3.0 **and** the [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) (which is the default storage engine for MongoDB versions >= 3.2), [Document Level Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency) control is used.

So with WiredTiger in your example, your updates could be run concurrently. If two threads or processes happen to attempt to update the same document at the same time, MongoDB will detect the write conflict and transparently retry.

See the [Concurrency FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Yes. I understand that while updating collection using 'db.collection.update()' mongo uses lock. I am specifically asking, if I am using bulk.initializeUnorderedBulkOp to update a collection. will it use lock?
And yes. I am using mongo 3.2

Comment: The bulk update is no different with respect to locking / concurrency.